# Add student to student ArrayList (java)

Tags: java, arrays, function, arraylist, methods

Before you read ahead, this is for my homework so the questions/answers are going to be specific.

I am writing some code that takes a student's name and adds it to the student ArrayList. I have a class for students and another class for a course (the course is where the add student and the ArrayList is ). The problem that I am having is that the code is restricting me from using some methods of the student class even though I have used them before. Also, the newly created student has to return the reference of the student, and if it fails it will return null. I have tried that but it has given me errors and I am unsure on how to incorporate the if-else function within the method.

Below is my code for the student class:

```
public class Student {
    // instance fields
    //class implementation
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private long studentId;
    private String loginId;

    private static int count = 10000001;


    private double[] quizMarks; //declare as an array

//constuctors

    public Student(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.studentId = studentId;

        quizMarks = new double[0];//initialize array


    }


    //accessors and mutator methods

    //set student's name and surname. Changing student's name does not affect the students' loginID

    public void Name(String name, String surname) {

    }

    //returns name and surname separated by comma (name, surname)
    public String setName() {

        return name + ", " + surname;
    }

}
```

class for Course:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Course{
    private ArrayList<Student> students;
    ArrayList<Double> quiz;

    public Course() {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        quiz = new ArrayList<Double>();
    }



    Student addStudent (String name, String familyName){
        students.add(setName(Name(name, familyName)));
        return null;
    }


    Student deleteStudent(long studentId){
        students.remove(studentId);
        return null;
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: You say that you get errors. What are they?

Comment: *"... the questions/answers are going to be specific"*.  If you review what you have written, you should see that you haven't actually asked a question at all.  Instead, you have given incomplete descriptions of problem.  1) *"... restricting me from using some methods ..."*.  Which methods?  How were you *trying* to use them? 2) *"... it has given me errors ..."*.  What errors?

Comment: In order for people help you, they need to understand what help you need.  You need to explain and / or show us what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
students.add(setName(Name(name, familyName)));
```

is not correct. You don't want to add a `String` to `stduents` you want a `Student`. Like,

```
students.add(new Student(name, familyName));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Course{
    // variables and constructors
    Student addStudent (String name, String familyName){
        students.setName(name, familyName);
        return null;
    }


    Student deleteStudent(long studentId){
        students.remove(studentId);
        return null;
    }

    }

}
```

There exists no Add or remove method in class Student so either you can add them in your format or correct that format.

```
public class Student {
    // variables
    // constuctors

    public Student(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.studentId = studentId;

        quizMarks = new double[0];//initialize array   
    }
    
    public Student remove(Student obj) {
    obj = null; //Destroying the reference
    }
      
    public void Name(String name, String surname) {

    }

    //returns name and surname separated by comma (name, surname)
    public String setName() {

        return name + ", " + surname;
    }
}
```